# Why is git repo mirroring a push operation?

Tags: git

I am wondering why git only supports `git push --mirror` and doesn't support `git fetch --mirror`. Is there some secret sauce which precludes a pull based mechanism, or is the idea to force replication to be managed from the source site, maybe to avoid a load storm if multiple mirrors pull at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

```
git pull --all --force
```

is close but if you want to delete local branches that are not on the remote and other implications of mirror, you could just use;

```
git clone --mirror
```

Comment: git clone --mirror is not incremental :) So it seems I must use git push. `git pull --all` is a false friend :) it doesn't do what you think it does :) `git fetch --prune origin +refs/*:refs/* just might work, need to test it...`

Comment: you could just use rsync.